# Shape of corners array returned by findChessboardCorners()

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using the OpenCV function `findChessboardCorners()` successfully, but I'm confused by the shape of the `corners` return value.

Here is my code below. I already know that my chessboard image has 8 x 6 internal corners.

```py
import cv2

nx = 8
ny = 6

img = cv2.imread('test_image2.png')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(img, (nx, ny), None)
print(corners.shape)
```

The last line prints: `(48, 1, 2)`.

Where does the `1` come from? I know there are 8 * 6 = `48` corners, and each corner has `2` coordinates. But what about the `1`?

The [documentation for findChessboardCorners()](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#cv2.findChessboardCorners) doesn't say anything about the `corners` result:

```
corners – Output array of detected corners.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an unwanted and unnecessary dimension, you can eliminate the dimension by using the [squeeze function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) of `numpy`:

```
 corners = np.squeeze(corners)
```

In [this documentation](http://csundergrad.science.uoit.ca/courses/cv-notes/notebooks/02-camera-calibration.html), they have also mentioned in comment line as **"extraneous singleton dimension"** :

> corners = np.squeeze(corners) # Get rid of extraneous singleton dimension

## **Edit:**

I simply switched the code to C++ side to dig into. Lastly, here is the code and console output of it:

```
std::ccorners<<corners.rows<<"  "<<corners.cols<<"  "<<corners.dims<<std::endl;
```

Output:

```
48 1  2
```

So the output you are getting gives respectively:

- rows number -> corner numbers
- column number -> 1 as default because there is only one data to give
- matrix dimensionality -> which is 2, number of data pair in each rows( coordinates )

Comment: I don't know if it's an "unnecessary" dimension, though. I would just like to understand why it's there.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 I edited my answer, that 1 represents the number of dimensionality of the corner output array

Comment: Thank you. I still don't understand what the `corners.cols` means. If `corners.cols` were, say, 3, would that means there are three (x,y) coordinates per corner? If so, how would that happen?

Comment: Actually, If you print the size of corners, you will get 1x48 which means 1 is column number and 48 is row number. So we understand that the matrix include 2 data pairs(x and y in this case) for each column

Comment: That's an interesting hypothesis. I passed to `findChessboardCorners()` arguments for `8x6` corners in the chessboard. I wonder why the `corners.col` and `corners.rows` are not `6` and `8` (or vice versa). Why is it `1` and `48`? That seems unintuitive.

Comment: I agree with you, 6x8 matrix is more readable than 1x48 but it looks like this is the architecture they designed.